# Custom Setting vs Custom metadata for keys/client Ids

Tags: apex

We want to move all of our secrets (api keys, endpoints, public/private keys, etc) related to several services to custom setting or to custom metadata, we are not sure what place is better.

These settings are going to be updated using a service rest called from a jenkins pipeline, then both components are valid due to can be updated using apex code.

My main concern is that metadata records are visible in the repository but really easy to get the value using a simple soql. On the other hand custom settings records are not in the repo but maybe more complicated to get....

So, what is your opinion?

Comment: afaik, Without going the route described by @SantanuBoral, there is no way to protect values from inspection by an authorized user (Sysad) except for Named Credential passwords - these can't be deployed from source either

Answer (score 1):

You should think of using protected Custom metadata types or protected custom settings for this use case.

For more information, refer [Protect Custom Metadata Types and Records](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/custom_metadata_types/custom_metadata_types_manageability)

Comment: in our case we are not using the concept of namespace/manage packages then protected is not valid for us....